# Regular Pentagon and Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, polygons, roots-of-unity

> $ABCDE$ is a regular pentagon of center $O$.
> Let $$\vec{V}=\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}+\vec{OE}$$
> Express $\vec{V}$ in terms of $\vec{OA}$, and then in terms of $\vec{OB}$. Conclude.

I tried to use Chasles relation and draw the vectors and add them up (4th vertex of the parm), but I was not able to reach a precise answer, and I feel like there is a much easier way to solve this.

I also tried giving each point a pair of coordinates but I couldn't reach the answer.

So this is my main question, finding $\vec{V}$ with simple math. (No matrices, maybe only vectors).

This question came as an activity before introducing the $n^{th}$ of a complex number, so I guess the conclusion is related to complex numbers, but finding $\vec{V}$ should be done algebraicly.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "This question came as an activity before introducing the nth of a complex number, so I guess the conclusion is related to complex numbers." -- Indeed. This is because those vertices lie all on a circle, and these vectors should sum up to whatever the center is. (For the $n$th roots of unity, that center is $0$.) In the case of a pentagon, we're looking at $n=5$. If you want a simpler idea, try a triangle or square instead first.

Comment: The 5th roots of unity are the solutions to $x^5=1$. Any 5 points that are evenly distributed on the unit circle will be the solution to $x^5=a$, where $a$ is a complex number with magnitude $1$ (if $|a|\neq 1$, then the roots will be distributed on a non-unit circle). We can prove that the sum of the nth roots of unity is $0$ by using viete's. Note that the sum of the roots of $x^n-1=0$ is $0$ by viete's. We can also prove it geometrically using the reasoning I sketched in my answer below.

Comment: In a triangle and a square the similar sum adds up to zero, so here we must also get that $\vec{V}=0$, but is there an easy way to prove it? And I didn't quite understand the conclusion, if you can please explain a bit more

Comment: I feel _certain_ this has been asked here before, but I'm not finding a good secondary reference. The key idea here (which can be made algebraic) is that since the set of five points is left unchanged by a rotation of 72 degrees about the origin, whatever their sum vector is it also has to be unchanged by a rotation of 72 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then we can use the rotation matrix
$$M=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\frac{2\pi}{5} & -\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}\\\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}&\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}\end{bmatrix}$$
to express all the vectors in terms of $\overrightarrow{OA}$. The expression for $\overrightarrow{V}$ simplifies to
$$\overrightarrow{V}=\left(M^0+M^1+M^2+M^3+M^4\right)\overrightarrow{OA}$$
$$\overrightarrow{V}=\begin{bmatrix} \sum_{k=0}^4 \cos\frac{2\pi k}{5}&\sum_{k=0}^4 -\sin\frac{2\pi k}{5}\\\sum_{k=0}^4 \sin\frac{2\pi k}{5}&\sum_{k=0}^4 \cos\frac{2\pi k}{5}\end{bmatrix}\overrightarrow{OA}$$
You can geometrically prove that this final matrix is the $2\times 2$ zero matrix by positioning a unit pentagon with two vertices on $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and then find the horizontal/vertical displacement as you go around the pentagon (instead of this geometric approach, you can also use complex numbers, but that defeats the point). Hence,
$$\overrightarrow{V}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\overrightarrow{OA}=\vec{0}$$